# MongoDB query to find all places within a circle

Tags: mongodb

**Structure of Documents:** (Facebook documents)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a984222daf2339b1e06090"),
    "name" : "Arts /entertainment/nightlife",
    "location" : {
        "state" : "",
        "country" : "Nigeria",
        "latitude" : 6.45306,
        "city" : "Lagos",
        "longitude" : 3.39583,
        "street" : "no 15 petre agha street oke -afa isolo lagos",
        "zip" : "+234"
    },
    "id" : "519994548127995",
    "category" : "Arts/entertainment/nightlife",
    "category_list" : [
        {
            "name" : "Arts &amp; Entertainment",
            "id" : "133436743388217"
        }
    ]
}
```

**My question:** What is the MongoDB query (using `$geoWithin: { $center: [ [ <x>, <y> ] , <radius> ] }` ) to find all the places that are within a circle?

**Circle:** Center: latitude = 48.856614 and longitude = 2.3522219000000177. Radius = 10 km.

I appreciate any answer that could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly modify the document structure for geo-spatial data as below.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a984222daf2339b1e06090"),
    "name" : "Arts /entertainment/nightlife",
    "state" : "",
    "country" : "Nigeria",
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            6.45306, 
            3.39583
        ]
    },
    "city" : "Lagos",
    "street" : "no 15 petre agha street oke -afa isolo lagos",
    "zip" : "+234",
    "id" : "519994548127995",
    "category" : "Arts/entertainment/nightlife",
    "category_list" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Arts &amp; Entertainment",
            "id" : "133436743388217"
        }
    ]
}
```

Create the **"2dsphere"** index on location field.

```
db.geocircle.createIndex( { location : "2dsphere" } );
```

Then, execute the find queries.

**The following queries should find Lagos.**

```
db.geocircle.find(
   { location: { $geoWithin: { $center: [ [ 6.45306, 3.39583], 10 ] } } }
);

db.geocircle.find(
   { location: { $geoWithin: { $center: [ [ 6.45310, 3.39590], 10 ] } } }
);
```

**This query shouldn't find Lagos.**

```
db.geocircle.find(
   { location: { $geoWithin: { $center: [ [ 16.45310, 3.39590], 10 ] } } }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any method to perform what i want without modifying the structure of the documents ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the coordinates should be defined like this. If you compare your model and my proposed model, there is not much change expect defining the location. Obviously, I have moved the other fields outside of location. For more information, you can refer http://blog.mlab.com/2014/08/a-primer-on-geospatial-data-and-mongodb/.

Comment: Okay, thank you that was really helpful. It is easy to change the structure anyways, but it is a little bit weird that with MongoDB we have to change the whole collection for just to be able to use queries related to geolocation.

Comment: Geo location is an unique structure. Are you ok to accept the answer if it is useful? Thanks!

Comment: I'm testing it. In about 20 min I will give you my feedback.

Comment: Thank you so much. Please check my answer below, there is an important remark that deserve a look.

Answer (score 4):

The answer of "notionquest" helped me to figure out the solution. But here is exactly my answer:

- **First Step**: change the structure of the documents in order to have the location field like this:

  ```
  "location" : [x , y]` where x is the latitude, and y is the longitude.
  ```
- **Second Step**: create the "2d" index on location field:

  ```
  db.geocircle.createIndex( { location : "2d" } );
  ```
- **Last step**: the query is:

  ```
  db.geocircle.find(
             { location: { $geoWithin: { $center: [ [ 48.856614,  2.3522219000000177], 0.089992801 ] } } }
  );
  ```

**Important note:** the radius of the circle in the query is in degrees, so I need to convert 10 km to degrees. Given that one degree is approximately 111.12 kilometers, we can do the math.

Cheers!

Comment: I believe you're mistaken. x corresponds to horizontal lines therefore it should be longitude. y is latitude. The index should be on the array [x,y] = [longitude, latitude]